Stuck on scraping with BeautifulSoup while learning. Need some pointers
I started learning screen scraping using BeautifulSoup. To get started I took a wikipedia article in the following format
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="width: 6%;" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Opening</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Title</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Director</th>
            <th style="width: 45%;" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Cast</th>
            <th style="width: 30%;" class="headerSort" tabindex="0" role="columnheader button" title="Sort ascending">Production company</th>
            <th class="unsortable" style="width: 1%;"><abbr title="Reference(s)">Ref.</abbr></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; background: #77bc83;">
                <b>
                    O<br />
                    C<br />
                    T
                </b>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" style="text-align: center; background: #77bc83;"><b>11</b></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <i><a href="/wiki/Viswam_(film)" title="Viswam (film)">Viswam</a></i>
            </td>
            <td>Sreenu Vaitla</td>
            <td>
                <link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1129693374" />
                <div class="hlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Gopichand_(actor)" title="Gopichand (actor)">Gopichand</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Kavya_Thapar" title="Kavya Thapar">Kavya Thapar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Vennela_Kishore" title="Vennela Kishore">Vennela Kishore</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Sunil" title="Sunil">Sunil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Naresh" title="Naresh">Naresh</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Chitralayam Studios<br />
                People Media Factory
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <sup id="cite_ref-180" class="reference">
                    <a href="#cite_note-180"><span class="cite-bracket">[</span>178<span class="cite-bracket">]</span></a>
                </sup>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; background: #77bc83;"><b>31</b></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <i><a href="/wiki/Lucky_Baskhar" title="Lucky Baskhar">Lucky Baskhar</a></i>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Venky_Atluri" title="Venky Atluri">Venky Atluri</a></td>
            <td>
                <link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1129693374" />
                <div class="hlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Dulquer_Salmaan" title="Dulquer Salmaan">Dulquer Salmaan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Meenakshi_Chaudhary" title="Meenakshi Chaudhary">Meenakshi Chaudhary</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/wiki/S._Radha_Krishna" title="S. Radha Krishna">Sithara Entertainments</a></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <sup id="cite_ref-181" class="reference">
                    <a href="#cite_note-181"><span class="cite-bracket">[</span>179<span class="cite-bracket">]</span></a>
                </sup>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <i><a href="/wiki/Mechanic_Rocky" title="Mechanic Rocky">Mechanic Rocky</a></i>
            </td>
            <td>Ravi Teja Mullapudi</td>
            <td>
                <link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1129693374" />
                <div class="hlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Vishwak_Sen" title="Vishwak Sen">Vishwak Sen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Meenakshi_Chaudhary" title="Meenakshi Chaudhary">Meenakshi Chaudhary</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>SRT Entertainments</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <sup id="cite_ref-182" class="reference">
                    <a href="#cite_note-182"><span class="cite-bracket">[</span>180<span class="cite-bracket">]</span></a>
                </sup>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background: #77ea83;">
                <b>
                    N<br />
                    O<br />
                    V
                </b>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background: #77ea83;"><b>9</b></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <i><a href="/wiki/Telusu_Kada" title="Telusu Kada">Telusu Kada</a></i>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Neeraja_Kona" title="Neeraja Kona">Neeraja Kona</a></td>
            <td>
                <link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1129693374" />
                <div class="hlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Siddhu_Jonnalagadda" title="Siddhu Jonnalagadda">Siddhu Jonnalagadda</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Raashii_Khanna" title="Raashii Khanna">Raashii Khanna</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Srinidhi_Shetty" title="Srinidhi Shetty">Srinidhi Shetty</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>People Media Factory</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <sup id="cite_ref-183" class="reference">
                    <a href="#cite_note-183"><span class="cite-bracket">[</span>181<span class="cite-bracket">]</span></a>
                </sup>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; background: #f4ca16; textcolor: #000;">
                <b>
                    D<br />
                    E<br />
                    C
                </b>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="1" style="text-align: center; background: #f8de7e;"><b>6</b></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <i><a href="/wiki/Pushpa_2:_The_Rule" title="Pushpa 2: The Rule">Pushpa 2: The Rule</a></i>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Sukumar" title="Sukumar">Sukumar</a></td>
            <td>
                <link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1129693374" />
                <div class="hlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Allu_Arjun" title="Allu Arjun">Allu Arjun</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Fahadh_Faasil" title="Fahadh Faasil">Fahadh Faasil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Rashmika_Mandanna" title="Rashmika Mandanna">Rashmika Mandanna</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Mythri_Movie_Makers" title="Mythri Movie Makers">Mythri Movie Makers</a></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <sup id="cite_ref-184" class="reference">
                    <a href="#cite_note-184"><span class="cite-bracket">[</span>182<span class="cite-bracket">]</span></a>
                </sup>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1" style="text-align: center; background: #f8de7e;"><b>20</b></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><i>Robinhood</i></td>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Venky_Kudumula" title="Venky Kudumula">Venky Kudumula</a></td>
            <td>
                <link rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style" href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1129693374" />
                <div class="hlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Nithiin" title="Nithiin">Nithiin</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/wiki/Sreeleela" title="Sreeleela">Sreeleela</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/wiki/Mythri_Movie_Makers" title="Mythri Movie Makers">Mythri Movie Makers</a></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <sup id="cite_ref-185" class="reference">
                    <a href="#cite_note-185"><span class="cite-bracket">[</span>183<span class="cite-bracket">]</span></a>
                </sup>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

This is my python script that I wrote:
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable"})
headers = ['month','day','movie','director','cast','producer','reference']
movie_tables = []
total_movies = 0
for table in tables:
    caption = table.find("caption")
    if not caption or not caption.get_text().strip():
        movie_tables.append(table)

#captions = soup.find_all("caption")

max_columns = len(headers)

# List to store dictionaries
data_dict_list = []

movies= []
for movie_table in movie_tables:
    table_rows = movie_table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")[1:]
    for table_row in table_rows:
        total_movies += 1
        columns = table_row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [col.get_text(strip=True) for col in columns]
        # If the row has fewer columns than the max, pad it with None
        if len(row_data) == 6:
            row_data.insert(0, None)
        elif len(row_data) == 5:
            row_data.insert(0, None)
            row_data.insert(1, None)
        for col in columns:
            li_tags = col.find_all('li')
            if li_tags:
                cast=""
                for li in li_tags:
                    li_values = li.get_text(strip=True)
                    cast = ', '.join(li_values)

                row_data.append(cast)
            else:
                row_data.append(col.get_text())
         # Create a dictionary mapping headers to row data
        row_dict = dict(zip(headers, row_data))
        
        # Append the dictionary to the list
        data_dict_list.append(row_dict)

# Print the list of dictionaries
for row_dict in data_dict_list:
    print(row_dict)

This is the output I am getting (Just showing a few items here):
{'month': 'OCT', 'day': '11', 'movie': 'Viswam', 'director': 'Sreenu Vaitla', 'cast': 'GopichandKavya ThaparVennela KishoreSunilNaresh', 'producer': 'Chitralayam StudiosPeople Media Factory', 'reference': '[178]'}

{'month': None, 'day': '31', 'movie': 'Lucky Baskhar', 'director': 'Venky Atluri', 'cast': 'Dulquer SalmaanMeenakshi Chaudhary', 'producer': 'Sithara Entertainments', 'reference': '[179]'}

{'month': None, 'day': None, 'movie': 'Mechanic Rocky', 'director': 'Ravi Teja Mullapudi', 'cast': 'Vishwak SenMeenakshi Chaudhary', 'producer': 'SRT Entertainments', 'reference': '[180]'}

{'month': 'NOV', 'day': '9', 'movie': 'Telusu Kada', 'director': 'Neeraja Kona', 'cast': 'Siddhu JonnalagaddaRaashii KhannaSrinidhi Shetty', 'producer': 'People Media Factory', 'reference': '[181]'}

{'month': 'DEC', 'day': '6', 'movie': 'Pushpa 2: The Rule', 'director': 'Sukumar', 'cast': 'Allu ArjunFahadh FaasilRashmika Mandanna', 'producer': 'Mythri Movie Makers', 'reference': '[182]'}

{'month': None, 'day': '20', 'movie': 'Robinhood', 'director': 'Venky Kudumula', 'cast': 'NithiinSreeleela', 'producer': 'Mythri Movie Makers', 'reference': '[183]'}

This is what I am trying to get(Just showing the last item here):
{'month': 'DEC', 'day': '20', 'movie': 'Robinhood', 'director': 'Venky Kudumula', 'cast': 'Nithiin|Sreeleela', 'producer': 'Mythri Movie Makers', 'reference': '[183]'}

I've been trying to debug this for the last day or so but I cannot figure out where I went wrong.
I am expecting:

the month, day filled up in all the items when those columns span multiple rows and are not represented in all rows.
Next, I want to have a separator between the different cast members so that it will be easy for me to create a graph later.
Also, how do I extract the hyperlinks and store in a separate key in the dictionary while doing all of this?


You need to supply the missing month ... I see nothing in the code where you do that. Maybe something like if len(row_data) == 5 then follow up with an update after insert: row_data[-1][0] = row_data[-2][0] .... i.e., the month is going to be the same as the previous row. Or maybe just loop through these rows after all the data is scraped to fill in the missing months.

I will do that. Any idea how to get the list values as a comma separated values for cast information in the table? I am inserting a '.' but it doesn't show up in the final result.

You can do most of the work using DataFrame
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(html_page))[0]
df.columns = ['month', 'day', 'movie', 'director', 'cast', 'producer', 'reference']
df['month'] = df['month'].str.split(' ').apply(''.join)
df['cast'] = df['cast'].str.split(r'\s{2,}', regex=True).apply(', '.join)

data_dict_list = df.to_dict('records')
for row_dict in data_dict_list:
    print(row_dict)

Output
{'month': 'OCT', 'day': 11, 'movie': 'Viswam', 'director': 'Sreenu Vaitla', 'cast': 'Gopichand, Kavya Thapar, Vennela Kishore, Sunil, Naresh', 'producer': 'Chitralayam Studios  People Media Factory', 'reference': '[178]'}
{'month': 'OCT', 'day': 31, 'movie': 'Lucky Baskhar', 'director': 'Venky Atluri', 'cast': 'Dulquer Salmaan, Meenakshi Chaudhary', 'producer': 'Sithara Entertainments', 'reference': '[179]'}
{'month': 'OCT', 'day': 31, 'movie': 'Mechanic Rocky', 'director': 'Ravi Teja Mullapudi', 'cast': 'Vishwak Sen, Meenakshi Chaudhary', 'producer': 'SRT Entertainments', 'reference': '[180]'}
{'month': 'NOV', 'day': 9, 'movie': 'Telusu Kada', 'director': 'Neeraja Kona', 'cast': 'Siddhu Jonnalagadda, Raashii Khanna, Srinidhi Shetty', 'producer': 'People Media Factory', 'reference': '[181]'}
{'month': 'DEC', 'day': 6, 'movie': 'Pushpa 2: The Rule', 'director': 'Sukumar', 'cast': 'Allu Arjun, Fahadh Faasil, Rashmika Mandanna', 'producer': 'Mythri Movie Makers', 'reference': '[182]'}
{'month': 'DEC', 'day': 20, 'movie': 'Robinhood', 'director': 'Venky Kudumula', 'cast': 'Nithiin, Sreeleela', 'producer': 'Mythri Movie Makers', 'reference': '[183]'}

To add the links as well you will have to use BeautifulSoup. You didn't mention the format, but you can do something like
df['href'] = None
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')[1:]
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    hrefs = row.find_all('a', href=True)
    df.at[i, 'href'] = [href['href'] for href in hrefs]

data_dict_list = df.to_dict('records')
for row_dict in data_dict_list:
    print(row_dict)

Output
{'month': 'OCT', 'day': 11, 'movie': 'Viswam', 'director': 'Sreenu Vaitla', 'cast': 'Gopichand, Kavya Thapar, Vennela Kishore, Sunil, Naresh', 'producer': 'Chitralayam Studios  People Media Factory', 'reference': '[178]', 'href': ['/wiki/Viswam_(film)', '/wiki/Gopichand_(actor)', '/wiki/Kavya_Thapar', '/wiki/Vennela_Kishore', '/wiki/Sunil', '/wiki/Naresh', '#cite_note-180']}
{'month': 'OCT', 'day': 31, 'movie': 'Lucky Baskhar', 'director': 'Venky Atluri', 'cast': 'Dulquer Salmaan, Meenakshi Chaudhary', 'producer': 'Sithara Entertainments', 'reference': '[179]', 'href': ['/wiki/Lucky_Baskhar', '/wiki/Venky_Atluri', '/wiki/Dulquer_Salmaan', '/wiki/Meenakshi_Chaudhary', '/wiki/S._Radha_Krishna', '#cite_note-181']}
{'month': 'OCT', 'day': 31, 'movie': 'Mechanic Rocky', 'director': 'Ravi Teja Mullapudi', 'cast': 'Vishwak Sen, Meenakshi Chaudhary', 'producer': 'SRT Entertainments', 'reference': '[180]', 'href': ['/wiki/Mechanic_Rocky', '/wiki/Vishwak_Sen', '/wiki/Meenakshi_Chaudhary', '#cite_note-182']}
{'month': 'NOV', 'day': 9, 'movie': 'Telusu Kada', 'director': 'Neeraja Kona', 'cast': 'Siddhu Jonnalagadda, Raashii Khanna, Srinidhi Shetty', 'producer': 'People Media Factory', 'reference': '[181]', 'href': ['/wiki/Telusu_Kada', '/wiki/Neeraja_Kona', '/wiki/Siddhu_Jonnalagadda', '/wiki/Raashii_Khanna', '/wiki/Srinidhi_Shetty', '#cite_note-183']}
{'month': 'DEC', 'day': 6, 'movie': 'Pushpa 2: The Rule', 'director': 'Sukumar', 'cast': 'Allu Arjun, Fahadh Faasil, Rashmika Mandanna', 'producer': 'Mythri Movie Makers', 'reference': '[182]', 'href': ['/wiki/Pushpa_2:_The_Rule', '/wiki/Sukumar', '/wiki/Allu_Arjun', '/wiki/Fahadh_Faasil', '/wiki/Rashmika_Mandanna', '/wiki/Mythri_Movie_Makers', '#cite_note-184']}
{'month': 'DEC', 'day': 20, 'movie': 'Robinhood', 'director': 'Venky Kudumula', 'cast': 'Nithiin, Sreeleela', 'producer': 'Mythri Movie Makers', 'reference': '[183]', 'href': ['/wiki/Venky_Kudumula', '/wiki/Nithiin', '/wiki/Sreeleela', '/wiki/Mythri_Movie_Makers', '#cite_note-185']}


Perfect. Thank you. Gave me enough pointers.
